# Are titles included when performing named entity recognition?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp

Using NER software like Stanford NLP or Apache OpenNLP, when training the model to recognize person names, do I have to include the title along with the name?

For example using Apache

```
<START:person> Robert M. Haugh, MD <END>
signed by <START:person> Dr. Holt B. Zolt <END>
```

VS

```
<START:person> Robert M. Haugh, <END> MD 
signed by Dr. <START:person> Holt B. Zolt <END>
```

Or using Stanford

```
At  O
the O
request O
of  O
Dr. PERS
Kelly   PERS
Schmeick    PERS
on  O
```

VS

```
At  O
the O
request O
of  O
Dr. O
Kelly   PERS
Schmeick    PERS
on  O
```

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally the title is not part of the PERSON name but gets it's own TITLE tag.  Our fine-grained pattern based NER detects titles, but the 4-class statistical model does not detect titles.